# Using the rectangular marquee tool with custom measurement scale

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Can one use the rectangular marquee tool in photoshop and specify a size based on the custom "measurement scale" specified in the "Analysis" tool.  I want to use it exactly like using the ruler tool when the "use measurement scale" box is checked.   Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to use the marquee tool to measure inches instead of pixels?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the size of the `Marquee` tool to whatever dimensions, in whatever units you want to use.

[image]

[image]

You can also use the marquee tool to measure units in Photoshop's default unit of measurement.

[image]